# ajax request $_get not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having problems sending get request in php with jquery. it just can't detect the get value
here are my codes:

```
 function getopmerking($id) {
            document.getElementById("popup_box").style.display = "block";
            $httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            $httpreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
                document.getElementById("txtouders").innerText = $httpreq.responseText;
                document.getElementById("requesteddata").innerText = $id;
            }

            $httpreq.open("GET", "files/request.php?q=1",true);
            $httpreq.send();

        }
```

and my php code:

```
    $id = $_GET["q"];
fetchData();
function fetchData()
{
    $drow = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `tblreservering` where fldllnid=$id;"));
    if(!empty($drow))
    {
        $drow['fldopmerking'];
    }else{
        echo "id is: ".$id."geen gegevens gevonden!"; 
        // i only get "id is: geen gegevens gevonden!" as output since $id is nothing.
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just a small note, you aren't sending an ajax request with jquery, you're sending an ajax request with javascript. And it looks relatively correct at this point, i guess depending on if you wanted to do anything with `$id` on the javascript side.

Comment: what's showing in the networks tab?  what debugging are you doing?  For a GET request, you should be able to put that AJAX URL right in the browser and see what happens, without the JS part.

Comment: Your variable `$id` is not in scope inside the PHP function `fetchData()`.  Pass it as a parameter to the function, or just retrieve it from `$_GET` inside the function.  And please don't forget to validate it as an integer!!!!!!  This is vulnerable to SQL injection as it is, and prone to break due to the nesting of `mysql_query()` inside `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Comment: You need to enable error reporting and display_errors, as PHP ought to be complaining about an undefined variable.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Seriously, listen to Michael Berkowski... your mysql call is SUPER unsafe... look up "SQL injection"

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this in JQuery, it would look like this:

JQuery:

```
function getopmerking($id) {
  $("#popup_box").show();
  $.get("files/request.php?q=1", function(resp){
    $("#txttouders").text(resp);
    $("#requesteddata").text($id);
  });
}
```

PHP:

```
$id = $_GET["q"];
fetchData($id);
function fetchData($getId){
  $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM  `tblreservering` where fldllnid=%d;", mysql_real_escape_string($getId));
    $drow = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    if(!empty($drow))
    {
        $drow['fldopmerking'];
    }else{
        echo "id is: ".$getId."geen gegevens gevonden!"; 
        // i only get "id is: geen gegevens gevonden!" as output since $id is nothing.
    }   
}
```

Comment: I still get this error when I use your code.
 Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolproject1\schoolproject1\files\request.php on line 5

Comment: Would need to see an example of the code you're running. The error suggests you are calling a variable name that has not been defined in your code. Update my example code above.